How to convert a polymer having OH groups to azide groups?
I am using Polypropylene glycol (PPG). I want to convert the OH groups in PPG to N3 (azide group). I tried to follow a reference which can be summarized as the alcohol was treated with PPh3, Iodine, Imidazole followed by Sodium azide dissolved in DMSO at RT. (doi of the reference is: doi.org/10.1007/s12039-012-0241-5)
However, as mentioned in the reference, Rokhum et al. have done column chromatography (C.C) to finally purify the product. But since my material is a polymer, it is very difficult to proceed with C.C. I have done normal work up using Diethyl ether and washing it with brine solution. But the catalyst PPh3 peaks are seen in NMR so I am not able to continue with this method. Can anyone suggest a better procedure for Polymer azide preparation from hydroxyl groups containing polymer?

Sorry but the question is not very clear, you have failed to say what the polymer is. Also are you attempting to follow a method from the literature, please give more details in your questions in future.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sorry for the inconvenience, I am using Polypropylene glycol (PPG). I want to convert the OH groups in PPG to N3 (azide group). Yes I tried to follow a reference  which can be summarized as the alcohol was treated with PPh3, Iodine, Imidazole followed by Sodium azide dissolved in DMSO at RT. (doi of the reference is: https://doi.org/10.1007/s12039-012-0241-5)

However, as mentioned in the reference, Rokhum et al. have done column chromatography (C.C) to finally purify the product. But since my material is a polymer, it is very difficult to proceed with C.C. I have done normal work up using Diethyl ether and washing it with brine solution. But the catalyst PPh3 peaks are seen in NMR so I am not able to continue with this method. Can anyone suggest a better procedure for Polymer azide preparation from hydroxyl groups containing polymer?

I suggest trying Mesylation (MsCl + Et3N, DCM) followed by NaN3

You should edit this info into your question.

Please provide all the details in the question body itself rather than in the comments. The more details, the better...

Thank you for your suggestion
